# Grails updates the model before saving

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

I am having trouble in validating and reseting some fields based on the role of a user.
I am trying to develop a rest api with grails and my problem appears when i try to reset some fields based on the role of an user. I send a json with the desired "not allowed" changes via PUT to the controller. I modify the not allowed fields to ones that are correct for me and then call .save() and the "not alowed" fields are updated with their sent value, not with the modified by me values. Here is the code.

THE MODEL

```
package phonebook

class User {
String firstName
String lastName
String phoneNo
String address
String email
String password
boolean active = false
String hash
String authToken = ""
String role = "user"

static hasMany = [contacts:Contact]

static constraints = {
    firstName(blank: false)
    lastName(blank: false)
    address(blank: true)
    phoneNo(unique: true)
    email(blank: false, unique: true)
    password(blank: false)
    role(blank: false, inList: ["user", "admin"])
    hash(blank: true)
    authToken(blank: true)
    active(inList:[true,false])
}
}
```

THE METHOD FROM CONTROLLER:

```
@Transactional
def update(User userInstance) {
    if (!isAuthenticated()){
        notAllowed()
        return
    }

    if (userInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    //if(isAdmin()){
       def userBackup = User.findById(userInstance.id)

       userInstance.role = userBackup.role
       userInstance.active = userBackup.active
       userInstance.hash = userBackup.hash
       userInstance.authToken = userBackup.authToken
    //}

    if (userInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond userInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    userInstance.save flush:false

    request.withFormat {
        '*'{ respond userInstance, [status: OK] }
    }
}
```

THE JSON SENT VIA PUT

```
{
"id":"1",
"firstName": "Modified Name 23",
"role":"admin",
"active":"true",
"hash":"asdasd"
}
```

The above code should not modify my values for hash or active or role even if they are sent.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "not allowed"? Do you mean that only particular users should be able to modify those fields-- with the problem being that other users seem to be able to modify those fields as well?

Comment: exactly. the problem is that even tough i counteract the changes, it still updates with the "not allowed" values sent

Answer (score 3):

The reason your changes are being saved is because by default any changes made to a domain instance will be flushed at the end of the session. This is known as open session in view with automatic session flushing. I recommend you do [some reading](http://spring.io/blog/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/) on some of the main issues people face with GORM.

Proper use of [discard](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/discard.html) may solve your issue. Discard your instance changes before you exit your controller.

For example:

```
if (!isAuthenticated()){
    notAllowed()
    userInstance.discard()
    return
}
```

**Edit**

Based on conversation in the comments this perhaps may be the way to address your issue. A combination of discard and attach.

```
   userInstance.discard()
   def userBackup = User.findById(userInstance.id)

   userInstance.role = userBackup.role
   userInstance.active = userBackup.active
   userInstance.hash = userBackup.hash
   userInstance.authToken = userBackup.authToken
   userInstance.attach()
```

Comment: the problem comes at the userBackup, beaqcuse of Hibernate , userBackup(taken from the database) and userInstance(fetched as parameter) are the SAME without calling save :(

Comment: This is because when you load userBackup it sees that the instance already exists in the Hibernate cache, which is the instance you loaded already and have modified. If you turn on SQL logging you will see it's not actually making another call to the database to load that record.

Answer (score 0):

I was helped by this method.

**[getPersistentValue](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getPersistentValue.html)**

Example

```
 def update(ShopItem shopItemInstance) {

    if (shopItemInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (!shopItemInstance.itemPhoto){
        shopItemInstance.itemPhoto = 
                shopItemInstance.getPersistentValue("itemPhoto");
    }

    if (shopItemInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond shopItemInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }


    shopItemInstance.save flush:true
    redirect(action: "show", id: shopItemInstance.id)
}
```

In your case:

```
   userInstance.role = userInstance.getPersistentValue("role")
   userInstance.active = userInstance.getPersistentValue("active")
   userInstance.hash = userInstance.getPersistentValue("hash")
   userInstance.authToken = userInstance.getPersistentValue("authToken")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you'll use the command objects feature. You can bind a command object with the request payload, validate it and than find and update the domain object.

You can find more details here: 
http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects

And off the record you shoudn't use @Transactional in your controller. You can move that code into a service.

Eq:

def update(Long id, UserCommand cmd){
 // Grails will map the json object  into the command object and will call the validate() method if the class is annotated with @Validatable

}